# How to install libssl on Debian 8?

Tags: debian

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
Release:        8.5
Codename:       jessie
```

I am installing a software which requires `libssl1.1`.

How / Where can I find this package for debian jessie 8.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian 8, you can install [the Debian 9 `libssl1.1` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libssl1.1/download):

```
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0j-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0j-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
```

Note that you will have to keep an eye on eventual security updates manually, or configure repositories with pinning to automatically pull `libssl1.1` from Debian 9 while avoiding a full-blown upgrade to Debian 9.

Comment: So `stretch` is debian 9 ? So he can just download the `.deb` file from the links down there.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer so it won't cause any problem for him.

Comment: Since you’d come up with the gist of it, I took the liberty of re-writing your answer rather than adding my own, I hope you don’t mind (feel free to revert if you do).

Comment: Ok no problem @StephenKitt

Comment: `On Debian 8, you can install the Debian 9 libssl1.1 package` Does this mean you can install a Debian 9 / Stretch package on Debian 8 / Jessie? Or is this a typo?